# Determining a Gene's Unknown Function

Tags: sequence-alignment, gene, sequence-analysis, sequence-annotation

I'm a beginner in this field (so pardon my rudimentary knowledge/explanation) trying to understand ways on how I could potentially identify genes of unknown function. I am trying to get as close as I can to the unknown gene's actual function.

What I've currently done, is that I've used an annotation tool to annotate my genome sample for its genes. From it, I've acquired a list of potential genes of unknown function, and I am capable of collecting its sequence. From here, I've also used BLASTn and BLASTp to align my gene sequences to find similar gene sequences.

From here, I'm absolutely clueless as to how I could proceed, since similarly sequenced genes are not always similarly functioned.
I would also like a list of other annotating tools, as well as other sequence alignment tools like BLAST, just so I could see the differences between tools.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi more detailsabout the genome, annotation and Blastp output please

Comment: Similar sequences may not always have the same function, but they're often similar enough to start with. Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the reasonably sufficient.